# jQuery & Checkbox: Works with checkboxes outside a table bot not inside

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am new to jquery but I managed to adapt code to my needs.
The idea is that I need a group of checkboxes where only 1 can be checked (radio buttons is not an option).

The following code works perfectly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>   
        <tr >    
            <input type='checkbox' class='ART2' id='ART2_DE'>DE
            <input type='checkbox' class='ART2' id='ART2_EN'>EN   
            <input type='checkbox' class='ART2' id='ART2_FR'>FR   

            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                $('input.ART2').on('change', function(evt) {if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= 1) { this.checked = false; }}); 
            </script>  

        </tr>   
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If I add data cells "< th >", the code doesn't work anymore.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>   
        <tr >    
            <th><input type='checkbox' class='ART2' id='ART2_DE'>DE</th>   
            <th><input type='checkbox' class='ART2' id='ART2_EN'>EN</th>   
            <th><input type='checkbox' class='ART2' id='ART2_FR'>FR</th>   

            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                $('input.ART2').on('change', function(evt) {if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= 1) { this.checked = false; }}); 
            </script>  

        </tr>   
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain my why?

Comment: When you include the checkboxes within <th> elements, the script is trying to find siblings of the checkboxes within the same <th> element, and since there are no siblings within the same <th>, the script doesn't work as expected.

To fix this, you can modify your HTML structure so that the checkboxes are directly within the <td> elements, and the <th> elements contain only the header text. check my answer for the code

Comment: [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) *Get the siblings* - ie all the elements with the *same* parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>   
        <tr>    
            <th><input type='checkbox' class='ART2' id='ART2_DE'>DE</th>   
            <th><input type='checkbox' class='ART2' id='ART2_EN'>EN</th>   
            <th><input type='checkbox' class='ART2' id='ART2_FR'>FR</th>   
        </tr>   

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $('input.ART2').on('change', function(evt) {
                var checkboxes = $(this).closest('table').find('input.ART2');
                checkboxes.not(this).prop('checked', false);
            }); 
        </script>  
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Hope this will solve your problem

```
    $("input.ART2").on('click',function() { 
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==true)
        var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
        $("input.ART2").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('id')!=thisId){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    }
});
```